# how to slidetoggle divs

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have year as category and months as subcategory. Now when I click the Year I need month to slidedown and when I click specific year month of other year should be hidden.

here is my code:

```
<div class="archiveevnt">
<h2 class="subhead3">2012</h2>
<ul class="event1">
<li>Feb</li>
<li>Mar</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="archiveevnt">
<h2 class="subhead3">2013</h2>
<ul class="event1">
<li>Jan</li>
<li>Feb</li>
<li>Mar</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('h2.subhead3').next('ul.event1').slideToggle();
        $('h2.subhead3').click(function(){
            $('h2.subhead3').next('ul.event1').slideUp();
            $(this).next('ul.event1').slideToggle();
            return false;
        })
    })
</script>
```

My problem is when i Click year month slidedown and now when i again click the same year month doesn't slideup.Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace this line of code:

```
$('h2.subhead3').next('ul.event1').slideUp();
```

with this:

```
$('h2.subhead3').not(this).next('ul.event1').slideUp();
```

- `$('h2.subhead3').not(this)` will select all the `subhead3` year elements except the element clicked in the current scope.
- Also since you were using `slideUp` on all the `subhead3` year elements and then the `slideToggle` for the current element. It resulted in the behaviour where clicking the same year month doesn't slideup, but slideup and then again down.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZH4rX/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove below extra line of code.

$(this).next('ul.event1').slideUp();

Below is the complete working code

$(document).ready(function(){


        $('h2.subhead3').next('ul.event1').slideToggle();


        $('h2.subhead3').click(function(){

            $(this).next('ul.event1').slideToggle();


            return false;
        })
    })